# Extract a subset of a neo4j graph filtering by nodes labels and properties types

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to extract a subset of data from a huge graph in `neo4j` (v.2.3) for copying that partition into a file.

I want to extract all data (i.e., labels/types and key-value attributes) of:

1. nodes with at least a label in a user-defined collection of labels;
2. relations binding node of point 1, with at least a type in a user-defined collection of types.

Let's say we have a graph like the following one:

```
CREATE 
(n:Label0:Label1 { name: 'NameA', title: 'TitleA' }),
(m:Label1:Label2:LabelBaz { name: 'NameB', title: 'TitleB' }),
(o:Label3 { name: 'NameC', title: 'TitleC' }),
(n)-[r:type0]->(m)
(m)-[s:type1]->(o)
```

If I specify:

1. `Label0`, `Label1`
2. `type0`

I should get nodes `n` and `m` and relation `r` with their details (i.e., labels/types and attributes)

If I specify:

1. `Label0`, `Label1`
2. `type0`, `type1`

I should get nodes `n` and `m` and relation `r` with their details.

If I specify:

1. `Label0`, `Label1`
2. `type1`

I should get nodes `n` and `m` with their details but no relationship.

Is there a way to get the partition with a couple of `Cypher` queries?

Comment: And what should happen when `Label0` and `type0` are specified?

Comment: You get just the node `n` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to get each relationship (whose type is in the `$types` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) and whose 2 end nodes have a label in the `$labels` parameter), along with its end nodes.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE
  TYPE(r) IN {types} AND
  ANY(l1 IN LABELS(n) WHERE l1 IN {labels}) AND
  ANY(l2 IN LABELS(m) WHERE l2 IN {labels})
RETURN r, n, m;
```

Note that this query would not be able to take advantage of any indexes (since the node types of interest are not static, and the query does not care about node properties). Therefore, the query time will increase as the number of nodes increases.

Comment: PS: Please note that my question is related to an old version of neo4j (version 2.3). Parameters syntax was slightly different (e.g., `{param}` )